# Convert Time in hh:mm:ss Format to Total Minutes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time, type-conversion, calculated-columns

I have the following sample input table below.  The `Time` column is in the format of `hh:mm:ss` or hours, minutes, and seconds.

| Name | Time |
| --- | --- |
| Jim | 1:33:04 |
| Chrissy | 0:06:39 |
| Billy | 10:00:02 |

The code to create the above table is:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':["Jim","Chrissy","Billy"], 'Time':['1:33:04', '0:06:39', '10:00:02']})
```

I want to create a new column called "_timemin" that converts the Time column to minutes.  For example, 10:00:02 would be equal to 600.03 minutes.

I tried to apply the following code but it didn't work:

```py
df['_timemin'] = df['Time'].str.split(':').apply(lambda x: (int(x[0])*60) + int(x[1])) + int(x[2]/60)
```

... the above code produces the error:

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression `df['_timemin'] = df['Time'].str.split(':').apply(lambda x: (int(x[0])*60) + int(x[1])) + int(x[2]/60)` has three issues:

1. Does not close the apply method
2. Applies (closes lambda x) to first two elements (x[0] and x[1]) only
3. Does not convert string x[2] to numerical data type before division

Here are two options:

`df['_timemin'] = df['Time'].str.split(':').apply(lambda x: int(x[0]) * 60 + int(x[1]) + int(x[2]) // 60)` floor (or integer) division to minute

`df['_timemin'] = df['Time'].str.split(':').apply(lambda x: int(x[0]) * 60 + int(x[1]) + int(x[2]) / 60)` floating minutes

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can achieve this using the datetime module to take your time and convert it minutes:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'Time': ['01:30:45', '02:15:20', '00:45:10']}  # Sample 'Time' data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function to convert HH:MM:SS format to minutes
def time_to_minutes(time_str):
    time_obj = datetime.strptime(time_str, "%H:%M:%S")
    total_minutes = time_obj.hour * 60 + time_obj.minute + time_obj.second / 60
    return total_minutes

# Applying the function to the DataFrame's 'Time' column
df['_timemin'] = df['Time'].apply(time_to_minutes)

print(df)
```